# What is the best codec and library in order to achieve wireless video and audio transmission through Raspberry and LoRa?

Tags: python, hardware, shared-libraries, gstreamer

I am currently working on a project where i want to create 2 wireless push to talk voice transmitters. I paired 2 Raspberry Pi with 2 LoRa antennas respectively in order to achieve that. However i am having trouble when I try to code using opus and gstreamer cause the lack of documentation especially on gstreamer's end. Is there a library or an easier way to create my project?

For reference i am trying to create something like this:
https://www.matchx.io/product/edge-x-ai-kit/

or this
https://www.kiwi-tec.com/en/products/lora-devices/lap-e01/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what does video have to do with "push-to-talk voice" ... however, for that, in my opinion, Opus is a good choice

Comment: At start i am just trying to transfer voice over LoRa. Secondary i will try to add a video not like a video call more like image transfer in order to let's say aggree simultaneously to change both receiver and transmitter frequency

Answer (score 2):

LoRa is NOT intended to be used for such a thing. LoRa operates in the free ISM band. As such there are rules that don't allow transmission over a long period (the maximum allowed transmission time is regulated by the local government) in order to allow other devices to also use the shared medium - thus reducing the air-time. Also LoRa uses transmission rates of 250bit/s with SF12 to 25kbit/s with SF7. This low transmission rates within the allowed air-time.

Comment: I am gonna minimize the packets size using opus codec (https://opus-codec.org/). Also legally it is not a problem here where i live. Also the voice would be a push to talk system like handheld transceiver that needs to forward military like commands not phone calls. That's why i think at least from a hardware point of view i am covered from LoRa and Raspberry.